Universal property of global spec of a quasicoherent sheaf of algebra
I am reading Vakil's FOAG (july31, 2023). Now in 17.1.C he gives an exercise:
Exercise. Given an $X$-morphism $\gamma:W\to\mathcal{S}pec \mathscr{R}$ where $\mathscr{R}$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra and $\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}$ is the global spec. Show that the morphism corresponding to $\gamma$ in the functorial bijection ($\mu:W\to X$ is the structure map of $W$)
$$Hom_{Sch_X}(W,\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R})\cong Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X-alg}(\mathscr{R},\mu_*\mathcal{O}_X)$$
is the composition
$$\mathscr{R}\to \beta_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}}\to \beta_*\gamma_*\mathcal{O}_W=\mu_*\mathcal{O}_W$$
(This bijection is the defining universal property of $\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}$. The morphism $\mathscr{R}\to\beta_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}}$ is an isomorphism, as the structure sheaf of the global spec is constructed by glueing.)
My attempts. The second arrow above comes from the map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}}\to\gamma_*\mathcal{O}_W$, which is from the $X$-morphism $\gamma:W\to\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}$. So we check this on open affine covering of $X$ (as the global spec is constructed by glueing anyways). Let $U=\operatorname{Spec}A\subseteq X$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{R}(U)& \cong \beta_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}}(U)\\
 &=\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}}(\operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathscr{R}))\\
& \xrightarrow{*}(\gamma_*\mathcal{O}_W)(\operatorname{Spec}\Gamma(\operatorname{Spec}A,\mathscr{R}))\\ 
&=(\gamma_*\mathcal{O}_W)(\beta^{-1}(U))\\
&=\mathcal{O}_W(\mu^{-1}(U))
\end{align*}
where the * part comes from the data $W\to\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}$. This made use of the fact that $\beta:\mathcal{S}pec\mathscr{R}\to X$ is affine and $\beta^{-1}(\operatorname{Spec}A)\cong \operatorname{Spec}(\mathscr{R}(\operatorname{Spec}A))$. This gives a map of sheaves on the basis, which should extend to a sheaf map.
Question.

How do we know that the map we get by extending is exactly the one the problem asks? They are both quite abstract anyways...

What is the insight of this problem? I would say I am pretty confused.


Any help is sincerely appreciated! Thanks!

I can only guess what Vakil intended the insight of the problem to be, but if I were to write an exposition of the relative spectrum I would include this exercise to get the reader to work out a "functorial" description of one direction of the bijection in the universal property of the construction, as opposed to a "gluing" description.
Vakil defines the relative spectrum by its universal property and shows that it exists by a general gluing argument, and this argument tells you (in principle) what the bijection
$$
\mathrm{Sch}_{/X}(W, \mathcal{Spec}\,\mathscr{B})
\to
\mathscr{O}_{X}\text{-Alg}(\mathscr{B}, \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W})
$$
looks like as a map of sets.  However, this gluing description can be inconvenient: given a map $\gamma : W \to \mathcal{Spec}\, \mathscr{B}$ of $X$-schemes, to describe the corresponding map $\alpha : \mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$ of $\mathscr{O}_{X}$-algebras we have to say something like "it's the map you get by gluing all the maps $\widetilde{B} \to (\mu\rvert_{U})_{*}\mathscr{O}_{U}$, where $V \subseteq X$ is an affine open, where $\mathscr{B}\rvert_{V} = \widetilde{B}$, and where $U \subseteq \mu^{-1}(V)$".  While this does uniquely characterize $\alpha$, it's not particularly convenient; for example, it requires making a choices like $V$, $B$, and $U$.
A second, more practical insight of this exercise is that whenever you have a map $W \to \mathcal{Spec}\,\mathscr{B}$ of $X$-schemes, there's only one "obvious" way to produce a map $\mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$ of $\mathscr{O}_{X}$-algebras.  If the universal property of the relative spectrum gave a map $\alpha : \mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$ distinct from $\mathscr{B} \to \beta_{*}\mathscr{O}_{\mathcal{Spec}\,\mathscr{B}} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$, then every time you wanted to use a map $W \to \mathcal{Spec}\, \mathscr{B}$ to conclude something about a map $\mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$, you'd need to ask yourself which of the two "obvious" maps $\mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$ is relevant for your result.  This exercise shows that you don't have to do that: however you turn a map $W \to \mathcal{Spec}\, \mathscr{B}$ into a map $\mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$, you'll get the same thing.
These motivations might help with answering your first question.  The attempt you give ends with "this gives a map of sheaves on the basis, which should extend to a sheaf map".  And it does, but we haven't shown that the resulting sheaf map coincides with $\mathscr{B} \to \beta_{*}\mathscr{O}_{\mathcal{Spec}\,\mathscr{B}} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$, which is what we're trying to show in the first place.  So this exact approach won't work.
Here's a different approach, based on the second possible insight I suggested.  We have one map $\alpha : \mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$ of $\mathscr{O}_{X}$-algebras corresponding to $\gamma$ under the universal property of $\mathcal{Spec}\, \mathscr{B}$, and we have another map $\beta_{*}\gamma^{\sharp} \cdot \phi : \mathscr{B} \to \mu_{*}\mathscr{O}_{W}$ of $\mathscr{O}_{X}$-algebras given in the problem statement.  We want to show that $\alpha = \beta_{*}\gamma^{\sharp} \cdot \phi$.  Since these are maps of sheaves, it suffices to show that they are equal over each element of an open cover of $X$.  Since $X$ is covered by affines, this means it suffices to consider the case where $X = \mathrm{Spec}\, A$ and $\mathscr{B} = \widetilde{B}$ for some $A$-algebra $B$.  Then $\mathcal{Spec}\, \mathscr{B} = \mathrm{Spec}\, B$, and $\phi : \widetilde{B} \to \beta_{*}\mathscr{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}\, B}$ is the identity map, so we need to show that $\alpha = \beta_{*}\gamma^{\sharp}$.  And this is Exercise 17.1.A.

Amazing answer! Also your suggestion on working out the functoriality is very helpful! Thanks.
